# Install OpenGApps in Android Studio Emulator (Marshmallow)

Tags: adb, android-emulator, mount, google-apps

I wanted to install OpenGApps in an Android emulator (created in Android Studio). The emulator is running with Marshmallow. There is enough storage space available, so this is not the problem. I tried everything which I found on Google, but it just wont work.

While the emulator is booting up, and I keep spamming `adb remount`, first it shows `remount succeeded`, and just after the desktop shows up, it suddenly says `remount of /system failed: Read-only file system` and `remount failed`.

So it doesn't work either when I try to push an OpenGApp `.apk` using `adb push`. If I try after booting up, it says: `adb: error: failed to copy 'Phonesky.apk' to '/system/priv-app/Phonesky.apk': Read-only file system` (or whatever the `.apk` is).

I can't remount `/system` with `rw` either: When I make the following:

```
$ adb shell
> *some remount command*
```

Following shows up: `mount: Read-only file system`. I tried it with various commands (substitute one of them with `*some remount command*`, the output is always the same):

- `mount -o rw,remount /system`
- `mount -o rw,remount /system /system`
- `mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/vba /system`
- `mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`
- `mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`

I also tried to run `su` after `adb shell`, but it had no effect either. I also tried to remount `rootfs` to `/` first with `rw`. This worked without an issue, but the remount for `/system` gave the same error as without remounting `rootfs`.

Could anyone help me with this struggle?

**Edit 1**: I also tried it with various different emulator settings, it didn't change a thing either. So I guess this problem is not depending on the emulator itself...

**Please note**: A bounty was offered to resolve this question, but I don't have much time for this at the moment. I would be grateful if you would ping me on twitter if an answer worked for you, so I can eventually accept it after I have tried it by myself. But this would save me a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that is possible on the default emulator. I would use Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Genymotion for all your emulator needs.
After getting Genymotion set up with emulated device of choice, [download ARM translation and GAPPS](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145).
Those files come in a .zip format, do not unpack them!

I would have normally installed ARM Translation which will let those ARM apps be able to run on this x86 virtual device. Afterwards Install GAPPS (make sure to use appropriate version for the system you are building). 
To install the above mentioned files I have used the drag and drop technique. Restart the device when done.
 Hope this helps

Comment: This is also how I would do it. Not sure if OP is considering using a different emulator. He might be stuck with the default one because of corporate computer or something.

Comment: It was more because of the fact that I never heard of that and was rather sceptical. But, and this is more important, I use the default emulator for a lot of things and I don't want to run a hundrets of emulators, each for different use cases...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem before. I solved it by adding this simple option and running the emulator through the command line:

> Note: you may need to adjust the slashes and `.exe` part if you use Linux, but the command args are the same.

```
<PATH_TO_EMULATOR>\emulator.exe -avd <YOUR_AVD> -partition-size 512
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Can someone confirm if this works? I am not able to test this in the next few weeks

Comment: I have seen this used before on the web so I am sure it should work, unless your specific emulator is wildly different.

Comment: Like I have said in the OP, I use the standard Android emulator from Android Studio. However, thanks for your answer but I can't accept an answer if it is not verified (I am kind of busy at the moment). I will try to verify it asap